# how to create app gateway in one resource group and vnet in other resource group using ARM templates

Tags: arm, azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway

I want to create an application gateway with two vm's inside one resource group and use another resource group for networking components

Answer (score 1):

like you normally would, just give it a subnet in that vnet?

```
resourceId('resource_group_name', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))
```

Reference:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-application-gateway-create/azuredeploy.json#L118
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-application-gateway-create/azuredeploy.json#L171